# Main menu level depth

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I would like to set 2 level depth in main menu (horizontal). I founded statement $category['level_depth'] > 1 in generateCategoriesMenu and I tried changed < 1 but this does not work. How can I set level depth ?

Comment: I added to css .top-menu ul li li {display: none !important;} this is working but I am not sure it is good practice.

Comment: What do you mean by 2 level depth ? Screenshot ?

Answer (score 1):

You should override module `ps_mainmenu` and in `ps_mainmenu.php` look at function `generateCategoriesMenu` and add this code:

```
if($category['level_depth'] > 2){
    continue;
}
```

in first foreach loop;